# Rollback first of two transactions

Tags: postgresql, transactions, rollback

Is it possible to make third step in PostgreSQL?

1. Make changes X to DB.
2. Make changes Y to DB that are based on changes X.
3. Rollback changes X.

If yes, please describe.

Comment: This would be possible if PostgreSQL could autonomously commit a subtransaction, or if it had autonomous transactions with the ability to perform dirty reads on another transaction. Neither is supported (by any DB, as far as I know), so you can't do this. RDBMSes are practically designed to *stop* you doing this. Why would you want to? What's the actual underlying problem you are attempting to solve here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Committing changes Y will commit also changes X. Think about it: If X was rolled back then relational consistency rules might break. Regardless of database engine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Changes X and Y doesn't cross each other (different tables), Y just uses values of updated rows in calculations.    Well, then I think I will save X changes to some variables, and then use it in Y changes.

Comment: But when X is rolled back, values from X which Y used will become invalid, or worse, will point to other unrelated data in X, and how you will distinguish between valid link to X in some Y rows and invalid in others? Of course it depends on kind of X values used in Y. If it is just some summary or average, it might be OK. But if you want to store in Y pointers to X and then deleting them, you are asking for problems.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Y doesn't save any pointers to X. I just implemented what I want in my PHP application - first I run X changes, then I SELECT what I need for Y, then I rollback X changes, then I use selected data for Y changes.